# Is that possible to make a world in which no one needs to speak?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, language, communication, telepathy

In my ideal world, everyone will be very very Intelligent. By that I mean everyone can think and feel what other people around them think and feel, so no one needs to talk with each other. Everyone will be synchronised with people around them.

How do I make this kind of world?

Comment: "Intelligent" does not mean telepath and telempath; it means good at solving problems. A telepath and telempath can still be dumb as a bag of rocks. The only possible meaning of the sentence "everyone will be synchronized with people around them" is that everybody has joined the [Rockettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rockettes). (Or, just possibly, you are using the word synchronized in a novel way, which you don't bother to explain because who cares.)

Comment: What I want for our race is far more important then Just being very Intelligent. I want to everyone to understand meaning of existence by understanding consciousness.

Comment: I don't understand what you are really asking. It's your world, you can just decide that the dominant is telepath and enlighted. What isn't "working"?

Comment: My world is fantasy for now . But idea behind my world is reality behind our consciousness so i have to follow it rules (absolute facts or absolute creation)

Answer (score 3):

All intelligent beings have communication.

All human communities have symbolic language.  It can be signed or spoken, but it is a formal language.

Language and higher cognition go together.  In general, they use overlapping and closely aligned parts of the brain.

Interestingly, some researchers make a case for formal language not being required.

> Is thought possible without language? Individuals with global aphasia,
>   who have almost no ability to understand or produce language, provide
>   a powerful opportunity to find out. Astonishingly, despite their
>   near-total loss of language, these individuals are nonetheless able to
>   add and subtract, solve logic problems, think about another person’s
>   thoughts, appreciate music, and successfully navigate their
>   environments. Further, neuroimaging studies show that healthy adults
>   strongly engage the brain’s language areas when they understand a
>   sentence, but not when they perform other nonlinguistic tasks like
>   arithmetic, storing information in working memory, inhibiting
>   prepotent responses, or listening to music. Taken together, these two
>   complementary lines of evidence provide a clear answer to the classic
>   question: many aspects of thought engage distinct brain regions from,
>   and do not depend on, language. ([ref](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4874898/))

I'm skeptical of the authors' conclusions.  After all, these are people who *can't* use symbolic language, not people who belong to a culture that doesn't use it.  And they are individuals who used to use language in a normal human way until their brain injury.

Thought is certainly possible without language.  My skepticism is that I don't believe intelligent nondisabled humans wouldn't spontaneously create language if they didn't already have one.

Look at communities where deaf children are not exposed to sign language and only get so-so training in the spoken language (even great training won't make you a native user if you're unable to hear it).  When these children get to spend time with other deaf children (or adults), they spontaneously create sign language.

One time this happened was in Nicaragua in the 1980's.  Children with special needs stayed at home until after the 1979 revolution that brought universal education.  But the schools for the deaf didn't teach sign, they taught lip reading.  The kids, however, used their free time together and a language sprang up (they had some influence from others but the language is completely original).

There are plenty of studies where children had no or limited or arrested language input who still latched on to language as soon as they had the chance.  It's part of human nature to use symbolic references.

So, yes, you can have thought without language, but no one with an option to choose to go without language does so.

If the only part of this you are asking about is the actual speech, then, yes of course, many people do not hear speech and many more do not use it.  Formal symbolic language does not require speech or even sound.

Comment: I don't think you think without language , there maybe different form of it(in case of deaf) but language is required for forming any kind solid thought or conclusion without that you can't make static memory

Comment: @earthling Then how do you remember images?

Comment: try to remember image and concentrate on mind background what you find is two thing 1) normally communication with your mind inform of language (ex: "try to remember" those words)2)  if your concentration was good then you will feel existence of consciousness in form of absolute tuning.

Comment: @earthling I have edited my post to indicate that language without speech is certainly possible.

Comment: @cys we can never know what's inside other's mind(deaf or anyone else) what you only know is what you are think (or ,you can think what are other's might think but that thought is still inside your mind only, or when I m typing this ans all the info and feeling behind it only inside my mind) so we are Limited by our consciousness no matter what, or i can say your world is your consciousness and everyone has their own world which can interpret this ans differently or interpret meaning of difference differently in short meaning of meaning is only limited      to your mind .

Answer (score 1):

Hive Mind

For no need of communication, everybody would have to be thinking the same thing. If everyone was part of a [hive mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_mind_(science_fiction)), they all be thinking the same thing.

In science fiction, they are usually portrayed badly due to the loss of individuality and free will but vastly intelligent.

Comment: Nice Concept but I want to everyone to live inside their mind as much as possible because that is the only key to find out what exactly self -awareness/conscious/mind is. so that everyone can reach the pick of living being .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the future we may have computers that know enough about ourselves that we don't need to communicate at all. The immense amount of data would be enough for things to work out.

Comment: Yeah that is also big possibility . Maybe we can connect our mind with internet like "transcendence"(Movie)

Answer (score 0):

You could have people develop a highly intricate yet unconscious body language. Essentially, all thoughts and feelings would be "leaked" by the body language, basically a side channel attack against the brain, except intentional (perhaps). In this way, people do not need to consciously tell each other things, all their thoughts and feelings are being transmitted all the time, and anyone who can see them can read these thoughts and feelings to obtain the information they need.

Comment: What I want for our race is far more important then Just being very Intelligent. I want to everyone to understand meaning of existence by understanding consciousness. because consciousness is everything. everything is created by it (If you can understand this statement ) let me give you my own definition of consciousness, Consciousness means creation of something (here something means everything and nothing)

Comment: @earthling Perhaps you should edit the question to note that. I was not aware of the consciousness requirement when writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give everyone a small rectangular device capable of sending and receiving messages with any other such device from anywhere in the world.  Make sending these messages faster and more convenient than verbal communication.  People know what the people around them thinking or feeling because they continuously send messages to globally-accessible repositories about their feelings which other people can read.  I shall call these devices "smart phones" and these repositories "social media".  I cannot imagine what such a world would be like, but it would eliminate the need for verbal interpersonal communication.